# MS SQL error : conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted error

Tags: sql-server

I am using MS SQL Server. One table column is defined as `order_date varchar(25)` and is stored in a format like `05/11/2015 07:54:16`

In my `select` query, I am trying to convert that into a date format like `(yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS:000`, e.g. `2015-05-11 08:03:10.000`

I have tried with

```
select CONVERT(varchar(50), CAST(order_date AS datetime),121) from <table>
```

In my table I have around 500 records, but after fetching 10 records in my expected format, I get this error error:

> The conversion of a `varchar` data type to a `datetime` data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Is there any issue with my conversion?

Comment: Do you have any NULLs in your table column?

Comment: *"am trying to convert that into date format "* This is totally the wrong approach. Stop storing dates as a `varchar` use a [date and time data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#DateandTimeDataTypes). The reason you have this error is because your poor data typoe choices. Fix that and get the presentation layer to work about the formatting.

Comment: I'd try to see what the value of `order_date` is at the time of the error. Perhaps what you assume to be a datetime in `mm/dd/yyyy...` format is actually in `dd/mm/yyyy...`

Comment: @twoleggedhorse, there are no NULL values in that column

Comment: @lamu, these are the legacy tables and we have to match that date with another table, hence we are trying to convert

Comment: in that case it's probably a different date format than what you expect

Comment: @GeethaAnand dates have no format, they are binary values. Use the correct type for dates, `datetime` or `datetime2`. Right now you have *no* way of knowing what format the stored strings use. MM/DD ? DD/MM? What if someone entered the wrong data, which seems to be the case here? If that's the case, how can you be sure about *any* of the data? 4/7 can easily mean April 7 or July 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. The first is your data type choice, but I'll just repeat my comment for that: *"*"am trying to convert that into date format "* *This is totally the wrong approach. Stop storing dates as a `varchar` use a [date and time data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#DateandTimeDataTypes). The reason you have this error is because your poor data type choices. Fix that and get the presentation layer to work about the formatting."*

Now, moving on. You have your expression below:

```
CONVERT(varchar(50), CAST(order_date AS datetime),121)
```

Firstly, as your value is a `varchar`, you need to tell SQL Server the format it is in; `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss` (I guess as `'05/11'` is ambigous)) is **not** unambiguous. What you have is the UK style, which is style 103:

```
CONVERT(datetime,'05/11/2015 07:54:16',103)
```

Now you can convert that to your ISO format:

```
CONVERT(varchar(23),CONVERT(datetime,'05/11/2015 07:54:16',103),121)
```

This returns the **`varchar`** value `'2015-11-05 07:54:16.000'`

Comment: Thank you.....yes i got the issue now, dates are stored in different formats....

Comment: As in the formats aren't consistent, @GeethaAnand ? If that is the case, the data is utterly meaningless. If one value, for example, is `01-02-03` that could be one of several **four** dates: 01 Feb 2003, 02 Jan 2003, 03 Feb 2001, 02 Mar 2001. If you don't know which format is the correct one, it literally has no value.

Comment: "dates are stored in different formats" - ... somebody's forked

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to see what the value of `order_date` is at the time of the error. Perhaps what you assume to be a datetime string in `mm/dd/yyyy...` format is actually in `dd/mm/yyyy...`.

I.e., the following outputs `2015-05-11 07:54:16.000` as my system is set to datetime format of `mm/dd/yyyy`.

```sql
    declare @order_date varchar(100) = '05/11/2015 07:54:16'; -- mm/dd/yyyy...
    print CONVERT(varchar(50), CAST(@order_date AS datetime),121);
```

the following throws an error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

```sql
    set @order_date = '13/09/2015 07:54:16'; -- dd/mm/yyyy...
    print CONVERT(varchar(50), CAST(@order_date AS datetime),121);
```